# Натуральная сортировка для строк, включающих цифры, буквы и символы

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, сортировка

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую сортировку использовать для данных в следующем случае:
на вход поступают строки адреса в формате:

`[City, State]`

Первоначально необходимо отсортировать их по [State] части. Здесь логично предположить alphabetic, ASC from A to Z.
Затем необходимо сортировать по [City] в рамках одного State.
Строка [City] может включать цифры, литеры в upped и lower case и символы (/-"').
В случае, если в строке [City] есть пробелы я их удаляю, и кроме того игнорирую регистр литер.

Желаемый результат:
из
'61 Address 0'
'123 Address'
'5 addr'
'5 addr1'
'12345asd'
'17Addr 1'
'5 asd10'
'01 city'
получить 
'01 city'
'5 addr'
'5 addr1'
'5 asd10'
'17Addr 1'
'61 Address 0'
'123 Address'
'12345asd'
То есть изначально сортировка идет по цифрам (если они есть в начале [City]), затем по литерам и цифрам. Приоритет: цифры, затем буквы, затем символы.

Первое предположение - использовать natural sorting, но не очевидны подводные камни. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как реализовать сортировку с такими условиями (желательно, с примеров "до" и "после" отсортированных строк.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вашу проблему, то можно так:

```js
const states = ['61 Address 0', '123 Address', '5 addr', '5 addr1', '12345asd', '107Addr 1', '5 asd10', '01 city'];

console.log(states.map(e => {
 // удаляем пробелы
 e = e.replace(/\s/g,'');

 // ищем место начала символов после начального номера
 let i=0;
 for(; i<e.length; i+=1)
  if(isNaN(e[i])) break; 

 // возвращаем объект с разделенными начальным номером и остатком
 return {
  head: e.substr(0, i),
     tail: e.substr(i),
 }
 // сортируем
}).sort((a,b) => {
 return a.head - b.head !== 0 ? a.head - b.head : a.tail < b.tail ? -1 : a.tail == b.tail ? 0 : 1;
 // собираем обратно
}).map(e => e.head+e.tail));
```